# Compiling NTFS-3G for OS X

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, ntfs, osxfuse, ntfs-3g

After noticing that the [recommended](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/NTFS-3G) installation of NTFS-3G is the five years old 2010.10.2 because it was conveniently available as .pkg, I wanted to give a try at compiling latest 2015.3.14 from [official website](https://www.tuxera.com/community/open-source-ntfs-3g/). *Please note that I do not want to install it from Brew or Macports, but install it manually*

So I tried:

```
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

But it told me `pkg-config` was not installed, so I installed it from http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/ using `./configure --with-internal-glib; make; sudo make install` and I got:

```
[...]
Making install in .
 ./install-sh -c -d '/usr/local/bin'
  /bin/sh ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c pkg-config '/usr/local/bin'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c pkg-config /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  install-exec-hook
cd /usr/local/bin && ln pkg-config x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0-pkg-config
ln: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0-pkg-config: File exists
make[3]: *** [install-exec-hook] Error 1
make[2]: *** [install-exec-am] Error 2
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

I ignored it and I tried again to install NTFS-3G:

```
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

But this time I got:

```
[...]
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /usr/local/lib/libntfs-3g.a(libntfs_3g_la-compat.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /usr/local/lib/libntfs-3g.a(libntfs_3g_la-debug.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /usr/local/lib/libntfs-3g.a(libntfs_3g_la-realpath.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  install-exec-hook
if [ ! "/lib" -ef "/usr/local/lib" ]; then \
        /bin/mv -f "//usr/local/lib"/libntfs-3g.so* "//lib";  \
    fi
mv: rename //usr/local/lib/libntfs-3g.so* to //lib/libntfs-3g.so*: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [install-exec-hook] Error 1
make[2]: *** [install-exec-am] Error 2
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Then I tried:

```
./configure --exec-prefix=/ && make && sudo make install
```

But I got:

```
[...]
install: //bin/ntfsfix: Operation not permitted
make[2]: *** [install-binPROGRAMS] Error 71
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Then I tried:

```
./configure --exec-prefix=/usr/local && make && sudo make install
```

But I got:

```
[...]
install: chmod 755 /sbin: Operation not permitted
ln -s -f /usr/local/sbin/mkntfs /sbin/mkfs.ntfs
ln: /sbin/mkfs.ntfs: Operation not permitted
make[3]: *** [install-exec-hook] Error 1
make[2]: *** [install-exec-am] Error 2
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

I'm using OS X 10.11 El Capitan.

Comment: Erik Larsson told me I should use `./configure --prefix=/usr/local --mandir=/usr/local/share/man --exec_prefix=/usr/local`, which gives the latest result of my question.

Comment: In case you didn't want to use brew because it didn't support building from the latest NTFS-3G source, it now accepts `brew install ntfs-3g --HEAD`, that does just that.

Comment: In any case you can just look at how homebrew does it and replicate those steps on your system https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-fuse/blob/master/Formula/ntfs-3g.rb

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears it was an issue from source. Erik Larsson made [a fix for it](https://sourceforge.net/p/ntfs-3g/ntfs-3g/ci/78ad037c662802ce8fb5bf297407f1ce8682be94/) on 23rd June 2015. Thank you very much. Now it is possible to compile from edge source git://git.code.sf.net/p/ntfs-3g/ntfs-3g

Preferably, get brew from http://brew.sh then install:

```
brew install automake
brew install libtool
brew install libgcrypt
brew install pkg-config
```

Then you can compile and install NTFS-3G (from its folder):

```
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --mandir=/usr/local/share/man --exec_prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

One drawback: both brew and ntfs-3g compete for folder /usr/local/.

Comment: I just sent a PR to homebrew/fuse in order to get a --HEAD switch to install ntfs-3g edge, so they don't compete. Will post an answer when accepted.